# Call async in sync foreach

Tags: c#

I've got external library with eventCallback defined like this :

```
public delegate void processEvent(string deviceType, string deviceId,string evtName, string format, string data);
        // event for event callback
        public event processEvent eventCallback;
```

in my code I subscribe to this event this way

```
app.eventCallback += ProcessEvent;
    protected void ProcessEvent(string deviceType, string deviceId, string eventName, string format, string data)
{
            var requests = GetRequests();
            foreach (var serviceRequest in requests)
        {   
            client.callAsync(serviceRequest)
        }
}
```

the question is how to call `client.callAsync` asynchronous ?
I can't change signature of `ProcessEvent` to return Task since then I cant bind it to `eventCallback += ProcessEvent;`

callAsync is async method

Should I create list of tasks and then wait for all or is there some better way ?

Comment: You could use a `BlockingCollection` or `ActionBlock` or other means of asynchronous go-between to tie the event producer and the actual processing together while keeping them separate. `ProcessEvent` would then simply squirrel away the request(s) for proper async processing somewhere else.

Comment: You're already calling it assynchrounously, you can check it yourself. Basically, siunce you are not awaiting the call, a Task will be scheduled on tha background and will run (most likely) in parallel.

Comment: Just add `async` to the method signature `protected async void ProcessEvent(string deviceType, string deviceId, string eventName, string format, string data)`, then change the call to `await client.callAsync(serviceRequest)`.  Might also want to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` here.

Comment: @Zer0 no I can't I told in my question I can't change signature of the event

Comment: Why can't you change `ProcessEvent` to add `async`?  This works fine if you're not changing the return type.

Comment: @Zer0 sorry you are right, seems it works, I coudn't change ProcesssEvent to return task, but adding async seems to works, you could add this as asnwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `async` to the method signature:

```
 protected async void ProcessEvent(string deviceType, string deviceId, string eventName, string format, string data)
```

This works because you aren't changing the return type.  Then change the call to:

```
await client.callAsync(serviceRequest);
```

Might also want to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` here.

If you want to run all service requests at once, asynchronously, change your `foreach` to:

```
await Task.WhenAll(requests.Select(x => client.callAsync(x));
```

Or you can use a collection of Tasks if you want.  Same effect.

Written as you have it your event handler does one request at a time.

If you want to *block* on every `Task` completing you can do this (which does not require async or await):

```
Task.WhenAll(requests.Select(x => client.callAsync(x)).Wait();
```

While they sound similar, [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) and [`Task.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.7.2) are conceptually very different things.  In short, the former is non-blocking, the latter is blocking.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but adding await in loop will not wait for every execution and this way make this code working sync ? Mabye better  create list of tasks and waitAll for them ?

Comment: what I need is to call all request in loop and wait till last one finish before returning this method.

Comment: @kosnkov Well, `await` is non-blocking.  So this method will return prior to all Tasks finishing...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to wait until all tasks finish before returning then I think there is no better way than creating a list of tasks and waiting for all. E.g.

`Task.WaitAll(requests.Select(x => Task.Run(async (x) => await client.callAsync(x)));`

Above code will run each task on a separate thread and then block the main thread until all of them ends.